# Формирование массива с учетом значений input

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Здравствуйте.
К примеру у меня есть инпуты:

```
<input name="arr[1][2]" value="a">
<input name="arr[1][3]" value="b">
<input name="arr[1][1]" value="c">
```

На выходе я получу массив:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [2] => a [3] => b [1] => c ) )
```

А как мне задать позицию значений этих? 
Вот если я получил инпуты как представлено выше, а массив должен сформироваться:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => c [2] => a [3] => b ) )
```

Пробовал asort, ksort и т.д, но не работает...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможно вы как-то не правильно использовали ksort?

```
$array = [1 => [2=>'c', 3 => 'a', 1 => 'b']];
ksort($array[1]);
print_r($array);
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => a
        )

)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6967188fd2b95e79d18441a43bd1568247362932

Конкретно ваш случай

```
$array = $_GET['arr'];
ksort($array[1]);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Ну да. Я там сам уже нешел - видимо с просони ksort вызывл с = 
($arr = ksort($arr[1]);